# select row not working in chrome and firefox (generated code)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

We are having some problems with browser support. Our application is working "fine" on internet explorer 11 with compatible view but some things are not working on firefox and chrome. The problem is that you cant select a row in a table. it's a javascript onclick function and i read that firefox and chrome expect a [return false] but the problem is that its auto generated code.

This is the (inline) code of the row's: `onclick="onSearchResultRowClick(4)"`

and the function:

```
function onSearchResultRowClick(rowNumber)
{
    selectRowInGrid('ctl17_ErfpachtrechtSearchView1_GridSearchResult', 'ctl17_ErfpachtrechtSearchView1_HiddenFieldSelectedSearchResult', rowNumber);
    enableOrDisableGridSearchResultButtons();
}
```

It would be great if someone has some kind of workaround or fix. 
Reminder i cant edit the onsearchresultrowclick function because its auto gen but i can add javascript code on a seperate js functions page.

Thanks in advance,
Raymond

Answer (score 0):

function setSelected(selRow, DataKey){ var tbl = document.getElementById("GridView1");for (var i = 1; i< tbl.rows.length; i++) {if(selRow.rowIndex == i) {selRow.className = "Selected Class";} else {tbl.rows[i].className = "Normal Class";} } document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = DataKey; }